# Me sale indentation error expected an intented block

Tags: python, click

Tengo un problema estoy haciendo un juego de memory de las cartas y solo puedo clickear con el mause izquierdo intente aumentarle para el derecho pero me sale

```
indentation error expected an intented block
```

Mi codigo es este

```
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      run = False
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
      if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()==(1,0,0):
        posX = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]//100
        posY = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]//200

        taken = memo.taken_cards(posX,posY,taken_pos)
        if taken == False:
          if card1 == False and card2 == False:
            card1_pos = [posX,posY]
            card1 = True
          elif card1 == True and card2 == False:
            card2_pos = [posX,posY]
            card2 = True
            for event in pygame.event.get():

    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
      if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()==(1,0,0):
       posX = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]//100
       posY = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]//200

       taken = memo.taken_cards(posX,posY,taken_pos)
        if taken == False:
          if card1 == False and card2 == False:
            card1_pos = [posX,posY]
            card1 = True
          elif card1 == True and card2 == False:
            card2_pos = [posX,posY]
            card2 = True
```

El codigo en el que me base originalmente es el siguiente:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      run = False
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
      if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()==(1,0,0):
        posX = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]//100
        posY = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]//200
        taken = memo.taken_cards(posX,posY,taken_pos)
        if taken == False:
          if card1 == False and card2 == False:
            card1_pos = [posX,posY]
            card1 = True
          elif card1 == True and card2 == False:
            card2_pos = [posX,posY]
            card2 = True
```

Comment: Y qué línea te señala el error?

Comment: me sale en la linea 33 en la parte de if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP: y me selecciona el if

Answer (score 0):

el error es bastante claro en lo que esta fallando, te esta diciendo que tienes un error de identación en alguna parte de tu codigo, en este caso es en bucle `for` donde reproduces el `for event in pygame.event.get():` ahora, recuerda que tu ciclo `for` lo que hace es revisar cada evento del juego a partir de la libreria `pygame`, por lo cual no es necesario que lo vuelvas a repetir, para ello es mejor solo hacer lo siguiente

```
for event in pygame.event.get(): #Se inicia bucle para registrar eventos dentro del entorno
  if event.type == pygame.QUIT: #Se valida que no se haya presionado salir
    run = False #Se termina el juego en caso de haber presionado salir 
  if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: #Se valida si se ha presionado un boton
    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()==(1,0,0) or pygame.mouse.get_pressed() == (0,1,0) or pygame.mouse.get_pressed() == (0,0,1):#Se validan los vectores de los botones que puede ser presionados
      posX = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]//100 #Se obtiene posicion en X
      posY = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]//200 #Se obtiene posicion en X
      taken = memo.taken_cards(posX,posY,taken_pos) #Se calcula un booleano a partir de la posicion del cursor y del objeto
      if taken == False: 
        if card1 == False and card2 == False: 
          card1_pos = [posX,posY]  
          card1 = True
        elif card1 == True and card2 == False:
          card2_pos = [posX,posY]
          card2 = True
```

Como se puede notar el unico cambio realizado fue la adición de las condicionales para los vectores correspondientes a los botones restantes en la linea

```
if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()==(1,0,0) or pygame.mouse.get_pressed() == (0,1,0) or pygame.mouse.get_pressed() == (0,0,1):
```

Comment: ahh tienes razon muchas gracias